# How can I edit my VIM config so that Vim treats ".ejs" files the same as it currently treats my html files?

Tags: html, vim, vi

What do I put in my vim config? How do I change it?

I want it to be like .html extension...because it is html...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ejs setfiletype html
```

`au` is short for `autocmd`

[docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html)

It's also a good idea to put it inside a test

```
if has("autocmd")
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ejs setfiletype html
endif
```

To avoid error messages if you ever use a cut-down version of Vim that doesn't support this feature.

Finally, if you have a default filetype rule like:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile * setfiletype text
```

then the `*.ejs` rule must be *above* it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me:

**au BufEnter *.ejs :setl filetype=html**

source: [How do I tell vim that some file extensions are synonymous?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-tell-vim-that-some-file-extensions-are-synonymous)

### Digging into the vim docs

1. *BufEnter* - "After entering a buffer.  Useful for setting options for a file    type. Also executed when starting to edit a buffer, after the    BufReadPost autocommands." *source: [BufEnter](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufEnter)*
2. *:setl* - "Like :set but set only the value local to the current buffer or window. Not all options have a local value. If the option does not have a local value the global value is set..." *source: [:setlocal](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:setlocal)*